# Laravel Echo with Soketi Not Broadcasting Events - Configuration Issue?

Tags: laravel, docker, websocket, redis, pusher

I want to trigger an event when a user's feed (of articles) is being updated. When the feed is updated, a `FeedGenerated` event is being broadcasted, and I would like my front-end to catch the event to allow user to manually refresh his feed.

The `FeedGenerated` event is being listened by the `UpdateFeedArticles` listener. This listener just Logs something for now (and it logs successfully).

The event is broadcasted as follow:

```php
FeedGenerated::broadcast($user);
```

The `FeedGenerated` event:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithBroadcasting;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class FeedGenerated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels, InteractsWithBroadcasting;


    /**
     * The name of the queue connection to use when broadcasting the event.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public string $connection = 'redis';

    /**
     * The name of the queue on which to place the broadcasting job.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public string $queue = 'default';

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new Channel("user"),
        ];
    }
}
```

The `UpdateFeedArticle` listener:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Providers\FeedGenerated;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class UpdateFeedArticles
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(FeedGenerated $event): void
    {
        \Log::debug('Event triggered', ['event' => $event, 'listener' => $this]);
    }
}
```

Laravel Echo instanciation:

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Websocket = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

Websocket.connector.pusher.connection.bind('connected', () => {
    console.log('✅ Soketi Connected!');
});

Websocket.connector.pusher.connection.bind('disconnected', () => {
    console.log(' Soketi Disconnected!');
});

Websocket.connector.pusher.connection.bind('failed', () => {
    console.log('❌ Soketi Connection Failed!');
});
```

Here is my `docker-composer.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  network_shapes:
    ipam:
      driver: default
    driver: bridge

services:
  phpfpm:
    container_name: '${APP_NAME}'
    build:
      args:
        user: '${WWWUSER}'
        uid: '${WWWGROUP}'
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - 'tmpfiles:/tmp'
    networks:
      - network_shapes
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped

  soketi:
    image: 'quay.io/soketi/soketi:latest-16-alpine'
    environment:
      SOKETI_DEBUG: '${SOKETI_DEBUG:-1}'
      SOKETI_METRICS_SERVER_PORT: '${SOKETI_METRICS_SERVER_PORT}'
    ports:
      - '${SOKETI_PORT:-6001}:6001'
      - '${SOKETI_METRICS_SERVER_PORT:-9601}:9601'
    networks:
      - network_shapes
    depends_on:
      - redis

  nginx:
    image: ${NGINX_IMAGE}
    networks:
      - network_shapes
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:${APP_PORT}:80'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/tkt.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - 'tmpfiles:/tmp'
    links:
      - phpfpm
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped

  mongo:
    ...

  redis:
    image: 'redis:latest'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:${REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis_volume:/data'
    networks:
      - network_shapes
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s
    restart: unless-stopped

  mariadb:
    ...

  mailhog:
    ...

volumes:
  tmpfiles:
    driver: local
  mariadb_volume:
    driver: local
  redis_volume:
    driver: local
```

Here is my Nginx `tkt.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost www.localhost .localhost *.localhost;

    index index.php index.html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location /mailhog/ {
        proxy_pass      http://mailhog:8025/;
        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location /websocket/ {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_read_timeout 86400; # Adjust to your needs
    }
}
```

## The situation

When running the command (that broadcast the event):

```bash
docker exec -t shapppes php artisan feed:generate 01h739jr4vk8pq3yefsp22c964
Scoring articles for Sonny Stroman...

Feed created.
```

Horizon logs the following:

```bash
docker exec -t shapppes php artisan horizon
Horizon started successfully.
  2023-08-07 13:04:56 App\Actions\Article\Feed\GenerateFeed .......... RUNNING
  2023-08-07 13:04:57 App\Actions\Article\Feed\GenerateFeed .... 899.66ms DONE
  2023-08-07 13:04:57 App\Providers\FeedGenerated .................... RUNNING
  2023-08-07 13:04:57 App\Providers\FeedGenerated ............... 61.82ms DONE
```

Redis is successfully querying (seen via Laravel Telescope)

```
eval -- Push the job onto the queue...
redis.call('rpush', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
-- Push a notification onto the "notify" queue...
redis.call('rpush', KEYS[2], 1) 2 queues:default queues:default:notify {"uuid":"bf2e429e-7702-4758-bedd-d072914a3215","displayName":"App\\Providers\\FeedGenerated","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"maxExceptions":null,"failOnTimeout":false,"backoff":null,"timeout":null,"retryUntil":null,"data":{"commandName":"Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent","command":"O:38:\"Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent\":14:{s:5:\"event\";O:27:\"App\\Providers\\FeedGenerated\":1:{s:4:\"user\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":5:{s:5:\"class\";s:15:\"App\\Models\\User\";s:2:\"id\";s:26:\"01h739jr4vk8pq3yefsp22c964\";s:9:\"relations\";a:4:{i:0;s:4:\"page\";i:1;s:14:\"page.bookmarks\";i:2;s:10:\"page.image\";i:3;s:4:\"tags\";}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";s:15:\"collectionClass\";N;}}s:5:\"tries\";N;s:7:\"timeout\";N;s:7:\"backoff\";N;s:13:\"maxExceptions\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:19:\"chainCatchCallbacks\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:11:\"afterCommit\";N;s:10:\"middleware\";a:0:{}s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"},"telescope_uuid":"99d54a11-c8fc-489f-8676-a575ab0466bf","id":"bf2e429e-7702-4758-bedd-d072914a3215","attempts":0,"type":"broadcast","tags":["App\\Models\\User:01h739jr4vk8pq3yefsp22c964"],"silenced":false,"pushedAt":"1691413497.6378"}
```

But nothing appears to be caught by Soketi (no Docker log).

Answer (score 0):

How to fix this issue:

Use your docker's service name with Laravel (`soketi` in my case), but use `127.0.0.1` with Laravel Echo (js).